# ошибка Syntax Error: invalid syntax в пайтоне

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
s = 1

for i in range(n):
    k = float(input()):
        if k > s:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Ошибка из-за k = float(input())

Comment: После k = float(input()) двоеточие не нужно и не нужен дополнительный отступ после него в строках ниже. Двоеточие нужно только в строках с while, for, if, def, class, with.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
s = 1

for i in range(n):
  k = float(input())
  if k > s:
    print(i)
```